# Forcing HTTPS on entire CodeIgniter driven site creates request loops... why?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, https

I have a pretty basic CodeIgniter setup for a site that now needs to be run entirely on SSL. So, I figured I need to force https by some .htaccess rules as that seems to be the most intuitive and straight forward approach. This is what I do:

config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://cooldomain.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove ugly index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1
```

The result is that I get lots of identical GET requests in my FireBug resulting in a "blank" error screen.

Doesn't CI URI patterns like .htaccess redirects? Surely this must work?

Comment: Seems like SSL is terminated on the load balancers of my clustered server provider. This causes the headache.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't

`RewriteCond %{S} off`

actually be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Because this answer came up quite high on my google search I'll answer this one.

Reading from the comments there seems to be a loadbalancer infront of the webserver. When this happens you can check the following as well to see if there's a https connection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
```